# Display an image by js in hybrid android app

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app

i am trying to pick image from the device and display it , but it's crash . i have tried and searched a lot but can not solve it .

here is my code :

```
javaBridge = new JavaBridge() {
            @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
            @Override
            public void pickImage() {
                Intent TestGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                TestGalleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                TestGalleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(TestGalleryIntent,PICK_IMG_REQUEST);
            }
        };
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(javaBridge,"javaBridge");
```

,here is onActivityResult .

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMG_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData() != null){
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            //Log.d("TOOOOOOOOOOT", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // returns null
            Log.d("PICTURE PATH :","-------->"+picturePath);
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayProfilePic('"+picturePath+"')");
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

,this is the JavaScript .

```
function pickImage(){
javaBridge.pickImage();
}


function displayProfilePic(imagePath){
document.getElementById("profilePic").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("profilePic").src=imagePath;
}
```

and this is the HTML .

```
<div class="file-input">
   <input class="image-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onclick="pickImage()" />
   <img class="image-upload" id="profilePic" src="">
  </div>
```

and after picking it up and trying to display it , it's appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6ees.jpg)

Comment: Do you use Cordova/React-Native ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin , no